# Adjust jquery parameter based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm working with this slider: http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/

You can see it here: http://www.fisherwallace.com/pages/treating-chronic-pain

The slider is responsive and looks good on large and small screens. However, screens between 941px and 1336px are an issue.

That's because the slider is set to start responding at 940px (responsiveUnder:'940') -- the width of the site content -- and not at 1336px -- the width of the images in the slider.

The slider width is set to 1336px... making it 940px is not acceptable as it cuts off the right and left edges of the images.

If I set the slider to start responding at 1336px (responsiveUnder:'1336'), by the time the content gets down to mobile, the slider is tiny.

So what I want to do is change the slider settings based upon screen size:

screen width > 940: responsiveUnder: '1336'

screen width <= 940: responsiveUnder: '940'

Here is the entire current slider code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
          slidedelay: '7000',
          showCircleTimer: false,
          skin: 'v5',
          navPrevNext: true,
          hoverPrevNext: false,
          navStartStop: true,
          navButtons: true,
          thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
          autoStart: true,
          autoPlayVideos: false,
          sliderFadeInDuration: '0',
          layersContainer:'940',
          responsive: false,
          responsiveUnder:'940'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I found this function that adjusts css based on screen width:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to bring the two pieces together.

For example, can I do...

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 940) {
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                  slidedelay: '7000',
                  showCircleTimer: false,
                  skin: 'v5',
                  navPrevNext: true,
                  hoverPrevNext: false,
                  navStartStop: true,
                  navButtons: true,
                  thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
                  autoStart: true,
                  autoPlayVideos: false,
                  sliderFadeInDuration: '0',
                  layersContainer:'940',
                  responsive: false,
                  responsiveUnder:'1336'
                });
    } else {
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                  slidedelay: '7000',
                  showCircleTimer: false,
                  skin: 'v5',
                  navPrevNext: true,
                  hoverPrevNext: false,
                  navStartStop: true,
                  navButtons: true,
                  thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
                  autoStart: true,
                  autoPlayVideos: false,
                  sliderFadeInDuration: '0',
                  layersContainer:'940',
                  responsive: false,
                  responsiveUnder:'940'
                });
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Help and advice appreciated... trying to learn!

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others who may need help with a  similar u.

With the help of a colleague, I found a solution.

To dynamically alter the jQuery "responsiveUnder" parameter based on screen width, you replace the value in pixels with...

```
(($(window).width() > 940) ? '1336' : '940')
```

So the full jQuery call is...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({

      slidedelay: '7000',
      showCircleTimer: false,
      skin: 'v5',
      navPrevNext: true,
      hoverPrevNext: false,
      navStartStop: true,
      navButtons: true,
      thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled',
      autoStart: true,
      autoPlayVideos: false,
      sliderFadeInDuration: '0',
      layersContainer:'940',
      responsive: false,
      responsiveUnder:(($(window).width() > 940) ? '1336' : '940')
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, is this responsive though? Will it adapt as you resize the window? It seems if you want it to be truly responsive, you'd need to add something that binds to the event of resizing the window.

Comment: It does not change the value dynamically... as when dragging your desktop browser narrower.  But what it does do is populate different values depending on the screen size you're using. And that's what I needed. Do you often view sites on 1300+ pixel wide desktops and then shrink the viewport to around 400 pixels?  Or is the objective having the site look good on any device. Thanks for downvoting my question., the only other contributor, and my answer as well.

Comment: Yeah, if that's sufficient for you, then that should work. But it's not truly responsive, in the sense of responding to resizing.

Comment: Lesson learned... won't answer my posts from now on. @rpl Instead of downvote, how about contributing something that would respond to resizing?